# $1^x = 1^y$ and $x,y$ belongs to Real Numbers.

Tags: exponentiation, real-numbers, fake-proofs

$1^x = 1^y$, and $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Following the rule, same base has powers equal every $x$ should be equal to every $y$.
$$1^x = 1^y$$
$$x = y$$
What went wrong?

Comment: For every rule you have to check the conditions for it to hold. There are always special cases. This is very similar to saying that $ax=ay$ implies $x=y$. It does, but only if $a\neq 0$. The same here. Take the logarithm of your equation and you will understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$1^x=1^y$ does not imply $x=y$:

$$x\cdot \ln(1)=y\cdot\ln(1)$$
$$x \cdot 0=y\cdot 0$$

Note that $x,y$ can be anything- including different values, i.e., $x ≠y.$

The rule you mention is incorrect.

Comment: How are you transforming 1^x = 1^y to x.ln(1) = y.ln(1)?

Comment: $\ln(a^b)=b\cdot \ln(a)$. You might want to brush up on your natural log properties: http://www.rapidtables.com/math/algebra/Ln.htm

Comment: thanks for your quick response. I got your point. But how is the rule wrong?

Comment: The rule is wrong because I just provided a counter example- an example where the "rule" doesn't work. However, try $n^a=n^b$ whenever $n≥2$. Notice that the rule works out then.

Answer (score 4):

Can you conclude that $2=3$ from this equation $ 1^2=1^3$?

Comment: That's not really an answer. The OP already indicates that something had to have gone wrong. Yes, $2\neq 3$. The question is *what* in the course of reasoning went wrong?

Comment: The answer of Paul is really a very good way to answer. Of course, it doesn't indicates immediately what went wrong in the course of reasoning. In fact, it is much valuable to give an hit to make think about. So that the enquirer could find by himself what mistake he made. The goal is not to give abruptly an answer to a question, but to help the requirer to improve his ability to reason and understand.

Answer (score 1):

The function $x\to 1^x$ isn't [injective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function).